# Reshaping data frame in r according to the longest row

Tags: r, dataframe, transformation

I have a 189 by 1443 data frame containing heart rate data for 189 days for every minute of the day:

```
year  month day   `00:00` `00:01` `00:02` `00:03` `00:04` `00:05` ...
2018   04   07      NA      63       NA      NA     62      NA    ...
2018   04   08      57      NA       58      NA     NA      NA    ...
2018   04   09      NA      NA       NA      52     NA      51    ...
```

I need to transform this data frame into 189 by 131 (which is the most amount of entries in one day), so basically align all entries to the left (in the way that the rows with <131 entries would have NAs from column x to 131).

The end result would have to look like this:

```
year  month day    `1`     `2`      `3`     `4`    `5`     `6`    ...  `131`
2018   04   07      63      62       63      64     61      60    ...   59
2018   04   08      57      58       56      55     56      55    ...   NA
2018   04   09      52      51       49      50     48      52    ...   NA
.
.
.
```

Could anyone help me with that? Sadly, I don't have a clue where to start.

Comment: Can you add a few rows/records to your example and add an example of your desired results. It's not clear exactly what you are going after.

Comment: I did, thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(minute, value, -c(year:day)) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  group_by(year, month, day) %>%
  arrange(year, month, day, minute) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  select(-minute) %>%
  spread(row, value)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   year, month, day [3]
   year month day     `1`   `2`
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2018 04    07       63    62
2  2018 04    08       57    58
3  2018 04    09       52    51
```